# Nested Google Maps Listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This nests Google Maps Event Listener for click or drag. How should I refactor the last part where it reuses the function `getAddressComponents()`? If there are other parts to be refactored, please do offer suggestions.

```
  function getAddressComponents() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        clearValue();
        if (results[0]) {
          // Get address_components
          for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
          {
            var addr = results[0].address_components[i];
            if (addr.types[0] == 'street_address')
              $('#spot_street_address').val(addr.long_name);
          }
        } else {
          alert('No results found. Please revise the address or adjust the map marker.');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Add drag listener to marker for reverse geocoding
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    getAddressComponents();
  });

  // Add click listener to marker for reverse geocoding
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    marker.setMap(null);
    addMarker(event.latLng);
    getAddressComponents();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
      getAddressComponents();
    });
  });
```

The map will have existing marker, which is draggable and geocodable. But once I click on the map to create a marker (thus, removing the existing marker), that new marker as I drag it, can't be geocodable. That's why I have to nest the listener to get it working. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', fgetAddressComponents);
```

And you don't need to add it twice. No need to add it in the `click` handler again.

Otherwise it's mostly ok, except for the `==` (instead of `===`), I just have styling nitpicks to say about this code.